# Compiling private to #property

Tags: typescript, compilation, private

Why does TSC not compile even with "target:ESnext" private class properties in #property?

Or maybe it will be done in the future?

The es2023 configuration gives an error, for ES2022 it is also not compiled into #property.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#31670](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670) for an authoritative answer to this question.

---

If TypeScript were to emit [a TypeScript `private` class property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private) as a [JavaScript private class member starting with `#`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), it would unfortunately be violating one of its language design goals.  [TypeScript Non-Goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) #5 is:

> Add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or **emit different code based on the results of the type system** (emphasis added). Instead, encourage programming patterns that do not require run-time metadata.

The problem is not the declaration site of the field, but in *uses* of the field.  TypeScript `private` properties are only *declared* as `private` but they are referred to with just their name:

```
class Foo {
    a = 1;
    private b = 2; // declaration
    method() {
        console.log(this.a + this.b); // use
    }
}
```

Note that `this.a` and `this.b` are of the same form, and are emitted to JavaScript without alteration:

```
/* class Foo {
    a = 1;
    b = 2; // declaration
    method() {
        console.log(this.a + this.b); // use
    }
} */
```

On the other hand, when you use a JavaScript private property, all references to it need to have the `#` sigil:

```
class Foo {
    a = 1;
    #b = 2; // declaration
    method() {
        console.log(this.a + this.#b) // use
    }    
}
```

It would be easy enough to have the keyword `private` emit as `#` for the declaration, but in order for the compiler to know that it should emit `this.a + this.#b` instead of `this.a + this.b`, it would have to be able to use TypeScript type system information to decide.  And that's against the rules.

---

So it doesn't happen now, and will almost certainly never happen; if someone were to file a feature request for it, such a request would be declined.  As it says in a [comment on microsoft/TypeScript#31670](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670#issuecomment-497370557) by the development lead of Microsoft's TypeScript team:

> Oh the other interpretation of [this suggestion] would be "Would TS emit `private` as `#`", the answer to which is definitely "no" because that would require type-directed emit.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PTNAvNAjANzqYAOATgJYBuYALgKbQBGu0ATIdAPTfQAmDUGHL1K8AHYkMAWwZ0AFvH4AKAJQppmDMEkR4IBgDoQ8AOYrFlCEewBqaFZvM1XXtACuEBloC+qf1RuACpoYSg4RE1tbDwiLVY8Th4+QWFROnEpbTlFZXVo7UxdCX1DE3NLBWtbaAcnIxc3Pi8fbX9faGDuVFRwmAAhEUKMWIJibQBiRI5mgSFwDKytXKVVDTQi4r0DY1MLBvtHaptpjXdWv17AoA)